# Is it possible to reproduce munsell colours on an android device?

Tags: screen

Given a wide variety of devices, is it possible to address the colour spaces such that a accurate reproduction of [munsell colours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munsell_color_system) are shown?

If it is possible, what applications can best be compared against a printed colour book to check an individual device's colour reproduction?

Answer (score 2):

Nearly all Android devices use the sRGB colourspace with 8 bits per channel, though some cheaper or older ones use 8 bits per channel in the framebuffer when the screen actually has a much lower bit depth, so it's not always possible to tell the real colour reproduction capabilities of the screen from the software configuration. If you have a table giving the closest sRGB equivalent to each Munsell colour, then the only question is how close you need it to be.

I don't know of any colour calibration tools, and [a quick search on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=colour+calibration&c=apps) didn't find any, so it's likely that no such software exists for Android. In any case, actually adjusting the on-screen colours to match the printed swatch would need you to have [root](/questions/tagged/root) on the device. Your best bet may be to use a paint tool or colour picker tool to show on the screen each colour you're interested in, and compare with the swatch that way.